# Angular Constant Array Best Practice

Tags: angularjs, constants

I'm wondering if it's good practice to define constants in angular for months. They months have internationalization data but I also want to track their English equivalents and numbers.

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .constant('DATES', {
            MONTHSABR: [
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-JAN"), "eng":"Jan", "raw": '01'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-FEB"), "eng":"Feb", "raw": '02'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-MAR"), "eng":"Mar", "raw": '03'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-APR"), "eng":"Apr", "raw": '04'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-MAY"), "eng":"May", "raw": '05'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-JUN"), "eng":"Jun", "raw": '06'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-JUL"), "eng":"Jul", "raw": '07'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-AUG"), "eng":"Aug", "raw": '08'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-SEP"), "eng":"Sep", "raw": '09'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-OCT"), "eng":"Oct", "raw": '10'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-NOV"), "eng":"Nov", "raw": '11'},
                {"i18n":Granite.I18n.get("MONTH-DEC"), "eng":"Dec", "raw": '12'}
                ],

        });
})();
```

In doing this, I'm ending up with structures in my code like the following:

```
var monthNamei18n = DATES.MONTHSABR[11].i18n;
```

Comment: I've moved this structure into a factory as I'm going to use the same factory to perform operations on the dates and return them. I'm still not sure if it's acceptable to define constants in the way I've outlined above though.